# Elastic Search Cluster Name Config

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

When I run curl 'http://localhost:9200/?pretty'

```
{
  "name" : "jk5lTpm",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch_neddannocise",
  "cluster_uuid" : "1GV0MUaCS66pPaaYcWkbfg",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "6.2.2",
    "build_hash" : "10a1add",
    "build_date" : "2018-02-16T19:01:30.685723Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "7.2.1",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "5.6.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "5.0.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

The value for "cluster_name" with neddannocise is the name of the user of my mac before I joined the company.

I am having issues with elasticsearch.

My current error error is

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to obtain node locks, tried [[/usr/local/var/elasticsearch/elasticsearch_neddannocise]] with lock id [0]; maybe these locations are not writable or multiple nodes were started without increasing [node.max_local_storage_nodes] (was [1])?
```

I have done a brew uninstall, then installed it again.

Any idea why this old user of my computer still is tied to elastic search somehow? How can I "start over" with elastic search?

Comment: Do you by chance have another instance of elastic running?

Comment: Yes, I believe I do. That is the issue? I've done a grep and killed the process. But it seems to start up again... a service or something? There is a guy who used to work here and it seems elastic search is still running under his config

Comment: My fear is that if I kill the process I wont get it going again... btw when I say "I've doe a grep and killed the process" I mean on another machine that I am setting up for a new developer...

Comment: He is starting new... so not afraid of "messing" with his env. I'm afraid to kill elastic search on mine.

Comment: Setting up a machine for a new developer should be a clean install. You're seeing the error on the new dev machine?

Comment: Yes. and a clean install.... yeah... agree %1000... but i'm not handing out the machine. It's dumb.... but here we are.

Comment: His dev machine... and mine... have the old users on them.... old settings ... etc.

Comment: Okay, then yeah, you should only have one elastic instance running. Are you able to run queries with curl? Just not in your code?

Comment: I can do curl 'http://localhost:9200/?pretty' and get a response. That response includes info related to this old user and cluster

Comment: Make sure elasticsearch is [uninstalled completely](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-completely-uninstall-elasticsearch/35832). Make sure any services that run it are disabled/removed and then do a clean install.